# Jquery 'click' not working while page is updating

Tags: jquery

My page reads a live stream and displays it on the screen. This is done by PHP using an SSH connection to the box and then running a specific command. The results from this are then displayed on screen and the screen is scrolled to the bottom so you always see the latest output. This works fine.

I've now created a button to stop this process. The button is in a fixed position on the page. When clicked it uses ajax to call an external page which kills the process I'm running.

The code is :

```
<input type='button' style='position: fixed; height: 15px; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 115px;' id='stop' name='stop' value='stop' />

 $('body').on('click','#stop' , function(){ 
    console.log ('clicked');
    $.ajax({ url : 'stop.php?id=123', 
 });
```

Clicking the button when the page isn't being updated works fine. I see 'clicked' and the results from the 'kill' in my console.

However when the page is being updated clicking the button does nothing. Nothing at all is shown in my console.

The stream results are shown using:

```
ob_flush(); flush();
echo (htmlentities($out);
ob_flush(); flush();
echo "<script>$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 400);</script>";
```

Anyway I can get the button to work whilst the page is being updated ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code of `$.ajax()`?, Also avoid using `$('body')` instead use `$(document)`

Comment: Is the request from the stream synchronous? That would stop the click being processed while data is being retrieved

Comment: @GhanshyamBaravaliya, As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated in favor of `.on()` see http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: the stop.php is just doing a kill -9 and the process ID.  It's not getting that far.

Comment: the page sends a command to the terminal, and then streams the results back to the page. I'd like to find a way to stop this if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
$('body').on('click','#stop', function() {  });
```

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#stop', function() {  });
```

Comment: changing that hasn't helped. It still does the same.

Comment: That's too bad, best of luck to you!